# Ternary operator error - "Expected expression"

Tags: objective-c, ternary-operator

I haven't used the ternary operator much and I'm getting an error on this:

```
(isInitializing) ? (return YES) : (isInitializing = 1);
```

Error is: "Expected Expression" and it's pointing to `return YES`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the Ternary Operator to "do stuff" but to return one of two values.
So this is a valid case:

```
NSString *something = (isInitializing ? @"value a" : @"value b");
```

In your case, you might want to do this instead:

```
if (isInitializing) {
  return YES;
} else {
  isInitializing = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator is used to return one of two values depending on a condition. It is not so much used to execute statements, hence the `return` is a bit of a problem. I would rather use an `if` when you do not want to distinguish values, but rather have two different execution paths.